# How to dynamically check number of arguments of an anonymous function?

Tags: octave

Part of my octave program takes an anonymous function from the user and evaluates it with random inputs. I want to make it as generalizable as possible so an arbitrary N dimensional function can be input, but I don't know how to dynamically determine the dimensionality of the input function.

Answer (score 1):

Given a function name or handle `fcn`, `nargin(fcn)` returns the declared number of input arguments.

[Reference](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/nargin.html).